# html5 video element and java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, apache-commons

I am trying to use `video` element on a page backed by `Spring MVC`. It works for the first `1.30` minutes or so, then the video freezes. On the server `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` occurs.

```
Spring MVC 4.1.1
commons-io 2.4
Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m
Tomcat 8.0.17 (Running with Eclipse Mars)
```

**HTML**

```
<video src="/mercury/somevideo" width="768" height="480" controls></video>
```

**Server (Spring MVC)**

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/somevideo" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void streamVideo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    InputStream is = null;
    try {           
        is = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\temp\\davideo.mp4")); 
        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.catching(e);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
    }
}
```

**The Exception** (After about 90 seconds of play)

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:393)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:339)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:418)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:406)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:97)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:457)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1793)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744)
at com.hurontg.mars.mvc.MemberController.streamMyPitch(MemberController.java:97)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:134)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:173)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:139)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:197)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:41)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:320)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:121)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:256)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388)
... 90 more
```

Comment: try to flush the response buffer `response.flushBuffer();` after copying.

Comment: @QuakeCore tried it, didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: The server is working correctly, it's the client that closes the connection.